# how to persist IE8 cookies in a VisualBasic web app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, cookies, internet-explorer-8

I wrote a web app on VisualBasic 2010, and cookies persist in all browsers except Internet Explorer 8.

the answer that follows solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by re-writing my cookie read and write methods.
(web app developed with VisualBasic2010 and runs on Windows Server 2008)

```
sub update_cookie_string( cookie_string, cookie_subkey  )

    dim cookie_object as HttpCookie     
    if request.cookies( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME ) is nothing then   ' PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME not at browser?
        cookie_object = new httpcookie( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME )           ' init cookie object as cookie named: PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME
    else
        cookie_object = request.cookies( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME )          ' Read cookie named PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME from page from browser
    End If

    cookie_object.Values( cookie_subkey ) = cookie_string       ' Update cookie_subkey with new value cookie_string
    cookie_object.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)           ' set expiration for a long time
    response.Cookies.add( cookie_object )                   ' Send it back to browser for storage there.
end sub



' Retrieve stored cookie_subkey.
function get_cookie_string( byval cookie_subkey  ) 
    dim cookie_object as HttpCookie     
    if  request.cookies( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME ) is nothing then  ' PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME not at browser?
        get_cookie_string = ""
    else
        get_cookie_string = Request.Cookies( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME )( cookie_subkey )  ' Return string value of cookie_subkey 
    End If
```